# Is there a setting to always start from the home screen on unlock?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, lock-screens

I am running Lollipop 5.0.2 on an LG phone.  Is there a setting to always start from the home screen on unlock?  Instead of trying to open the last open application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AOSP ROM doesn't have such setting and neither did I ever hear about such setting in any other ROM. Anyhow, if you are comfortable with app based solutions then you can consider any of the following apps for the objective.

[Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) (7-day trial) does it nicely.

1. Profile: Event → Display → Display Off or Display Unlocked
2. Task → Actions: App → Go Home.

Done!

---

[Macrodroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid) (free for up to five macros) can also help.

Macro:

1. Trigger: Screen Unlocked or Screen On/Off → Screen Off
2. Action: Launch Home Screen
3. Constraints: Choose depending upon the trigger or leave it untouched

Done!

---

[AutomateIt](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=AutomateIt.mainPackage) (free) works too.

Rule:

1. Trigger: Screen Off Trigger or Screen On Trigger
2. Action: Launch Home Screen Action
3. Rule: Show rule popup when launched → No

Done!

---

[Atooma](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.atooma) is also doing well here.

1. IF: Screen → Screen On
2. DO: App Launcher → choose your launcher app

Done!